# Using AT commands

Tags: c#, at-command

I want to dial a phone using AT command.I did it successfully. Now i want to get last call duration..In order to get that i tried with AT+CLCC Command..It should return some string..But still it won't.
Here is my c# code...

```
string phonenr = "";
//  string mesaj;
if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
{
     _serialPort.Open();
}
_serialPort.WriteLine("AT\r");

{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the phone number:", phonenr);
    phonenr = Console.ReadLine();
    _serialPort.WriteLine("ATD" + phonenr + ";" + "\r");
    Console.WriteLine("Ring...");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);


    _serialPort.WriteLine("AT"+"CLAC");
    _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);



private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{   
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.Write(indata);
}
```

How could i do this????I want to asign the return string to variable

Answer (score 3):

On this line:

```
_serialPort.WriteLine("AT"+"CLAC");
```

It should be:

```
_serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CLAC");
```

Comment: Hi there,I also tried with that....But result is the same...

Answer (score 1):

"Don't roll your own."

Use the GSMCommands library. It is specifically built for SMS management, but allows you to send custom commands as well.

It's free.

http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply...And how should i do it...???